# Is this port a Cortex Debug?

Tags: stm32, debugging, swd, st-link

The following is a board with an [STM32F103](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f103.html) MCU.

Is it possible to tell if the marked port on the top left (JK1) is a Cortex Debug port that may be connectable with an [ST-Link V2](https://opencircuit.shop/ContentImage/102799/crop/900-600/ST-Link-V2-STM8-STM32-programmer.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) or similar ?

According to [some](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448575/correct-wiring-of-cortex-m-10-pin-debug-connector) [online references](https://itectec.com/electrical/electronic-correct-wiring-of-cortex-m-10-pin-debug-connector/) the pins used for the LQFPR48's debug port are PA13,PA14,PA15,PB3 & PB4.

**UPDATE**: PA13(SWDIO) and PA14 (SWDCLK) have traces all the way to the header but it's hard to see on which pin they end up. The back side has a wide LCD display connector and white wrapping which makes it hard to see where one trace go to and the other has a trace that seem to end up on two holes. GND is the filled hole with no traces (I've tested it for continuity). So that leaves me with finding Vcc, and the other 2 SWD signals positions.

Also, the port's holes do not fit with a 2.54mm which is typical for a pin header and also the connector wires that comes with the ST-Link v2 (Chinese clone). I'll appreciate any suggestions or enlightenments.

[image: Board and pin out]

Comment: what do you mean "the traces don't look like it"? PA13 and Pa14 seem very much connected to that header.

Comment: Which board is it? What does the manual say? Maybe it does not support full JTAG but SWD only? It also looks like the serial port pins also go there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, but PA14 looks like it's connected to two pins one above the other. And PA13 is not clear where it ends up. Also what would be the voltage pin ?

Comment: why can't you just use a multimeter in continuity mode and check for definite which pins are connected?

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture but the JTAG/SWD port seems to go there. RN5 looks like pullup/downs for the JTAG. Take an ohm meter and figure it out, then make your own cable.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?